# How is this specific answer not "not an answer"?

Tags: support, specific-answer, disputed-flags

Answer in question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30589831

It is a post by the OP, clearly meant as an edit to their question. I made the edit and flagged the answer. But the flag was disputed.

What am I missing?

If flagging such things is wrong, can someone explain why to me and I won't bother in future?

Comment: It's not easy at all to determine if it's a clarification of the question or a self-answer.  Whichever it is, it's certainly not a clear case.

Comment: It's just not _obviously_ not an answer.

Comment: Users comment on the question: `Please check my code and thanks for help` (posted 21 seconds after their answer) -- I posit that it **is** easy / obvious / clear if you make an effort and read the posts

Comment: Yes, the comment makes it obvious that it's not an answer. But... do the Low Quality Posts reviewers see the question comments when reviewing an answer? I would have gone with a "needs moderator attention" flag instead.

Comment: @TZHX The comment posted to the question (and not the answer) that doesn't even reference the answer, and that would make sense even if they had never posted an answer?  Given that you've pointed that out, I'd say it's a strong point in the "isn't an answer" column, but it's nowhere near "obvious".  If one needs to read the comments on the question to determine that the answer isn't an answer, then it's not a *clear* case at all

Comment: @Servy I disagree, but I don't think we'll change each others minds on this. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @AJPerez: We do.

Comment: I did also flag it and got it disputed. Then I noticed that you need the context of the question and comments to see it is not an answer. So I ended up adding a comment, in the hope it would be handled later on.

Comment: @fedorqui I could understand it being disputed, perhaps, if someone edited it. I do not understand how someone could click "Looks OK". And I would have though looking at the *question* when determining if something is *not an answer*, **especially when the post is by the same user** would be something people should be doing.

Comment: @TZHX I am not saying I agree with thei "Looks OK" at all, but sometimes users post a block of code answering their original question, so I guess this is what people clicking "Looks OK" thought.

Answer (score 20):

So, first things first:  it's a disputed flag, not a *declined* flag.  Some poor soul felt like this was a valid answer when we both know it isn't.

Disputed flags don't hurt you, so don't worry about it.

Now, you've decided to edit the answer into the question - where it belongs in this case - so I'd recommend that you downvote the answer, as it fits the rationale of a downvote fine (not useful).

I'm not sure you can flag it again, but if you can, do so.

Comment: Right, gotcha.  I'm half-awake.  I really shouldn't Overflow before my morning tea.

Comment: That's what you get for being in the wrong timezone. :p OK, I couldn't raise a NAA flag so I raised a custom flag. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Another helpful thing would be to leave a comment on the answer explicitly describing what you are doing.  Something like: "This is a clarification of the question, so I am moving this into the question.  Please use the edit button in the future. Reviewers, please delete this answer."

Comment: regarding "I'm not sure you can flag it again, but if you can, do so": as far as I know, one can't raise the same disputed flag again becouse that option will still be marked as "you have already raised this type of flag". That would then need a custom flag mod-flag (since we shouldn't flag for the wrong reason, and the right reason is now unavailable).